# How to store a datatable in cache to reuse it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching

In my application I have used a generic handler to serve requests.

I want a mechanism like, if the first time request comes to the handler, it makes a request to the server and then caches the whole datatable, so for upcoming requests if the next requested productcode  exists in the cached datatable, it should not go to the server for fetching data again; it should check the data of the cached datatable only.

How can I set up a datatable in the cache?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Something along these lines?

```
public DataTable GetDataTableFromCacheOrDatabase()
{
   DataTable dataTable = HttpContext.Current.Cache["secret key"] as DataTable;
   if(dataTable == null)
   {
       dataTable = GetDataTableFromDatabase();
       HttpContext.Current.Cache["secret key"] = dataTable;
   }
   return dataTable;
}
```

You're going to need some mechanism to flush the data table from the cache if it changes. For example you could use an [SqlCacheDependency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.sqlcachedependency.aspx).

As requested, to clear the cache an hour after the table is added you would do:

```
HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert("secret key", dataTable, null, DateTime.Now.AddHours(1), System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
```

Comment: Not thread-safe... what if the cache entry is removed between the `if` and the `return`?

Comment: @Thomas Levesque - That is highly unlikely.

Comment: @JonH, highly unlikely things happen all the time... if it can happen, it probably will, sooner or later (that's roughly the idea behind Murphy's law)

Comment: @Thomas Levesque - I guess then you weigh the risk of that.  Not everything is worth the time or effort.

Comment: It's no effort.  Got to agree with Thomas, this kind of code can bite you in the ass,  and when it does it takes at least 10 times as long to track it down as it does to write it well in the first place.

Comment: @James Gaunt - I was referring to murphy's law :).

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
 DataTable mytable;
 String key = "key"
 if(HttpContext.Current.Cache[Key] ==null)
 {
        mytable = GetDTFromDB();
        if(mytable.Rows.Count > 0)
            HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert(strKey, mytable, Nothing, DateTime.Now.AddHours(1), System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
    else
        mytable = HttpContext.Current.Cache[strKey];
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use:

```
HttpContext.Current.Cache["CacheDataTableID"] = datatableInstance;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can write a property for your table like

```
public DataTable CachedTable  { get{ 
      if(Cache["CachedTable"] == null) 
     { 
       Cache["CachedTable"]= //get from databse 
      } 
      return Cache["CachedTable"]; 
    }  }
```