# GridView SORTING of DYNAMIC Columns and Data Source Scope issues

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sorting, gridview, datatable

**READ FIRST**
I re-wrote this to make it more readable. If you want to skip right to the chase, look at the ALL CAPS comments in the code blocks. All necessary code has been included for debugging.

I've searched multiple forums (including ASP.NET), and the MSDN library and cannot fix this >.<

**GOAL**: To dynamically generate a table/grid-like "status report" containing up to 20+ depending on user-specified columns (*consideration: should be able to be stored in a cookie for user prefs*). This grid will contain data provided from a View on the SQL Server, and row must be clickable. Pagination was super easy to implement, but the **sorting** has proven to be a nasty challenge.

**ISSUE (Scope)**: I decided to re-post all the relevant code to make it easier to troubleshoot.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        chooseColumns()
    End If
End Sub

Protected Function queryToDataSet() As ArrayList
    'Code removed: Function returns the Columns to select from
End Function

'Handles the button click to build the `GridView` from the selected columns
Protected Sub ShowGrid(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnSub.Click
    For Each item As ListItem In chkFields.Items
        If item.Selected Then
            Dim b As New BoundField()
            b.DataField = item.Value
            b.HeaderText = item.Value
            b.SortExpression = item.Value
            statusReportGrid.Columns.Add(b)
        End If
    Next
--> Me.GetData() 'HERE'S THE SCOPING ISSUE... UPON EXIT THE DATASOURCE IS LOST
End Sub

Private Sub GetData()
    statusReportGrid.DataSource = StatusDS
    statusReportGrid.DataBind()
End Sub

Protected Sub statusReportGrid_Sorting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewSortEventArgs) Handles statusReportGrid.Sorting
    'CODE BREAKS HERE because the DataSource is no longer in scope
    Dim dataTable As DataTable = TryCast(statusReportGrid.DataSource, DataTable)
    If dataTable IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim dvSortedView As New DataView(dataTable)
        'The following line (when working properly) should return a string
        '  something like "StatusColumn DESC" for example. This format
        '  doesn't make sense to me and doesn't seem correct.
        dvSortedView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + getSortDirectionString(e.SortDirection)
        statusReportGrid.DataSource = dvSortedView
        statusReportGrid.DataBind()
    End If
End Sub

Private Function getSortDirectionString(ByVal sortDirection As SortDirection) As String
    Dim newSortDirection As String = String.Empty
    Select Case sortDirection
        Case sortDirection.Ascending
            newSortDirection = "ASC"
        Case sortDirection.Descending
            newSortDirection = "DESC"
    End Select
    Return newSortDirection
End Function
```

**ASP CONTROLS**
`GridView` control (minus the styling stuff) - The tutorials I've read said to set the `EnableViewState` to false. When trying it with a setting of true I get repeated columns on refresh.

```
<asp:GridView ID="statusReportGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True"
    EnableViewState="False" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True"></asp:GridView>
```

Primary `SqlDataSource` control for the status report content.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="StatusDS" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:StatusDBConnectionString %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [StatusTable]">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

**THE PROBLEM**
I just discovered this to be an issue of scope as once my calling function that causes the `DataSource` to be bound to my `GridView` exits, the `DataSource` then becomes empty. I would certainly appreciate some help resolving my scoping issues so that my `DataSource` remains available and modifiable by all functions in the codebehind. It should be persistent as long as the page is being displayed more or less.

Comment: Stop in the debugger before that line is executed, and look at the value of `dvSortedView.Table`. Also, look at the type of statusReportGrid.DataSource.

Comment: Both have `nothing` in them which I already know is the problem, I just don't know WHY the values aren't getting passed. It's obvious to me something is in my DataSource or I wouldn't be seeing the GridView records in my browser. I tried using the `sender` object too and same result.

Comment: We would have to see the code that sets DataSource to begin with, and any other code that changes it. Also, check to see if the grid has ViewState enabled. If not, then DataSource will be empty on PostBack.

Comment: @John Saunders It appears that even setting ViewState to true doesn't resolve the problem. For some reason when I handle the `Sorting` event, the `DataSource` of the `GridView` doesn't get passed in, even though it is "bound" to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of doing what you want without a DataSource Control, using a code behind DataTable & Cache along with a custom SortDirection function that manages the sort direction in the view state.

```
''' <summary>
''' Show Grid
''' </summary>
''' <param name="sender"></param>
''' <param name="e"></param>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Protected Sub ShowGrid(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ShowGridButton.Click
    BuildGrid()
End Sub

''' <summary>
''' Sort GridView Columns
''' </summary>
''' <param name="sender"></param>
''' <param name="e"></param>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Protected Sub Sorting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewSortEventArgs) Handles statusReportGrid.Sorting
    Dim dataTable As DataTable = BuildData()

    If DataTable IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim dvSortedView As New DataView(dataTable)

        dvSortedView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + getSortDirectionString()
        statusReportGrid.DataSource = dvSortedView
        statusReportGrid.DataBind()
    End If

End Sub

''' <summary>
''' Get and Store GridView SortDirection
''' </summary>
''' <returns></returns>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Private Function getSortDirectionString() As String
    Dim sortDirection As String = "ASC"

    If ViewState("GridSortDirection") IsNot Nothing Then
        If ViewState("GridSortDirection").ToString() = "ASC" Then
            sortDirection = "DESC"
        Else
            sortDirection = "ASC"
        End If
    End If

    ViewState("GridSortDirection") = sortDirection

    Return sortDirection
End Function

''' <summary>
''' Build Dynamic GridView Columns
''' </summary>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Protected Sub BuildGrid()
    Dim dataTable As New DataTable
    dataTable = BuildData()

    If dataTable.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        For Each item As ListItem In chkFields.Items
            If item.Selected Then
                Dim b As New BoundField()
                b.DataField = item.Value
                b.HeaderText = item.Value
                b.SortExpression = item.Value
                statusReportGrid.Columns.Add(b)
            End If
        Next

        statusReportGrid.DataSource = dataTable
        statusReportGrid.DataBind()
    End If
End Sub

''' <summary>
''' Get DataTable from DB and Use Cache to Store 
''' </summary>
''' <returns></returns>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Protected Function BuildData() As DataTable
    Dim dataTable As New DataTable

    If Cache("StatusDBResults") IsNot Nothing Then
        dataTable = TryCast(Cache("StatusDBResults"), DataTable)
        Return dataTable
    End If

    Dim queryString As String
    queryString = "SELECT * FROM [StatusTable]"

    Using connection As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("StatusDBConnectionString").ConnectionString)
        Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter()
        adapter.SelectCommand = New SqlCommand(queryString, connection)
        adapter.Fill(dataTable)

        'Add To Cache for 2 Minutes for Sorting/Paging/Downloading
        Cache.Add("StatusDBResults", dataTable, Nothing, System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, New TimeSpan(0, 2, 0), System.Web.Caching.CacheItemPriority.Default, Nothing)

        'MY CODE - Gets the Column Names and dumps them into the ASP.NET CheckBoxList control
        'There may be a better way to do this using the DataTable, but I wasn't able to get that to work. This works and it's pretty fast.
        connection.Open()
        Dim colQuery As New SqlCommand("select column_name from information_schema.columns where table_name = 'StatusTable'", connection)
        Dim dr As SqlDataReader = colQuery.ExecuteReader
        Dim colsArr As New ArrayList
        While dr.Read
            colsArr.Add(dr.Item(0))
        End While
        chkFields.DataSource = colsArr
        chkFields.DataBind()

        Return dataTable
    End Using
End Function
```

Here is my sample HTML control source that I used for the test....

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" ID="statusReportGrid">
</asp:GridView>
<asp:CheckBoxList runat="server" ID="chkFields" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Flow" />
<asp:Button runat="server" Text="Button" ID="ShowGridButton" />
```

Let me know if this makes sense, I don't normally code in VB.  The SortDirection is a known issue, because it always returns Ascending.  As for the use of a DataTable vs SqlDataSource, both can be used but I find the DataTable approach easier.

Comment: *sigh* Didn't work unfortunately, though it does make my code a bit cleaner.

Comment: That sounds PERFECT. Would you please elaborate a bit on how to implement that? I'm not really familiar with the technique you're describing. I ordered a book on Data Controls, but in the meantime I'm stumped >.<

Comment: Here is a link to a [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6831665/how-to-store-datatable-in-cache-to-reuse-it) that shows an example of using Cache to store your DataTable.

Comment: Doh, my added code presents a bug. After requesting the columns and the Table being built, when you re-select columns they get appended because of ViewState being true by default and because your Cache checking function returns before the column array can be reset. You're still my freaking HERO for getting me this far though, haha.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are setting the DataSource to be your new DataView, when you come back again, you no longer have a DataTable - just the DataView. So your TryCast will produce Nothing.

I have no idea why the `IsNot Nothing` is succeeding.

Comment: I have no idea either mate, but that's how they do it [here](http://forums.asp.net/p/956540/1177923.aspx) and in numerous other forums and examples. As to your `IsNot` comment, please see the note I just added to my question. Sorry about the confusion.