# User based Caching in webservice

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, caching

I want to cache a dataset in webservices in ASP.net using C#.
Also, the dataset belongs to different user.
i.e. Each user will have a different cache which will expire after some time.

Could anybody suggest a nice approach for this.

Answer (score 1):

Cache is application specific. But if you want to store the user specific cache, you can include user session id key in it. It might consume lot of memory ( depending upon number of users) and hence should be carefully considered.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a key that is specific to the user to cache the data. For example: `__username__data` where `username` will differ.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the ASP.NET session state to store the data. it saved per user and expire after some time (that you can configure).

here is a little article explain what you need to do to implement session at your service:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480509.aspx

Comment: Note that storing data in a session can be dangerous. Session is decoupled from membership. Google "ASP.NET session stealing".

Answer (score -1):

you can find the answer here
[How to store datatable in cache to reuse it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6831665/how-to-store-datatable-in-cache-to-reuse-it)

In your case choose "secret key" as unique attribute of a user (for instance, userid, username or email)