# Using ViewState for Persisting Data to Reuse it for Binding Dropdowns

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, mvp

Working on a sample with `Repository Pattern` in `MVP(Model View Presenter) Framework`

**Work Scenario**

I am using a `Telerik Grid` which is using data from 4 tables which i am getting using `Include`, 3 tables among them are look-ups.

I want user to be able to `Edit Records` and `Insert new records` into the grid.
so I need to `Bind` the `Drop downs` from look-up tables in the `Add/Edit Records Form`.

**Problem/Confusion**

For Binding drop downs i don't wanna make another `Database Call` so i am thinking of using the `data-source of grid only` by  maintaining it in a `view state`.

like this

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Sets List of Case Info's  into grid datasource
    /// </summary>
    List<CaseInfo> ICaseInformationGridView.CaseInfoList
    {
        set
        {
            radgrid1.DataSource = value;
            ViewState["randomName"] = value;
        }
    }
```

Would this be a good approach if not should i go for the approach of making properties for look-ups, and using them accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the `ViewState` will be much slower comparing to db access. If viewstate, you are storing the values to populate the dropdown in the clients page. If you want that data from clients page, he had to post the page back to server (including this viewstate content).

Data transfer between client and server are mostly depend on the clients internet connection. Please don't give an overhead to client side.

Asp.net provides different types of caching to manage these kind of unwanted server loads.
See such a StackOverflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6831665/how-to-store-datatable-in-cache-to-reuse-it).