# Persist information in DataTable

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

I have a datatable which is bound to a Gridview on page to show data.
then I have a Add new button which opens up a Usercontrol in a Bootstrap Modal.

This Addnew usercontrol needs to have a form to enter the details

- ID
- Address
- State
- City
- Country

These details are added to the datatable.

Right now there is no database involved.

DataTable is initiated then few string type columns are added to it then rows are added , all this in Pageload of Webform than there is a AddNew button which opens a UserControl in this UserControl there are labels and Textboxes and a add button , I need to Add a row in the Datatable initiated in the Webform in this Usercontrol.

Following is the code on the Webform

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
   //if (!IsPostBack)
   //{
     DataTable mytestdata = new DataTable();
     Session["DataTable"] = mytestdata;

     if (mytestdata.Columns.Count == 0)
     {
       mytestdata.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(string));
       mytestdata.Columns.Add("Address 1", typeof(string));
       mytestdata.Columns.Add("Street", typeof(string));
       mytestdata.Columns.Add("City", typeof(string));
       mytestdata.Columns.Add("Post Code", typeof(string));
       mytestdata.Columns.Add("Country", typeof(string));
      }

     if (mytestdata.Rows.Count == 0)
     {
       mytestdata.Rows.Add("1341", "Number 49", "Phibsboro", "Dublin 2",             
       "11111", "Ireland");
       mytestdata.Rows.Add("1241", "Number 46", "Dundrum", "Dublin 6",    
       "124354", "uk");
       mytestdata.Rows.Add("1351", "Number 43", "Phibsboro", "Dublin 7",  
       "23445", "Ireland");
       mytestdata.Rows.Add("1141", "Number 59", "Dundrum", "Dublin 8",  
       "11111", "uk");
       mytestdata.Rows.Add("1234", "Number 69", "Dundrum", "Dublin 9",  
       "23432", "Ireland");
       mytestdata.Rows.Add("1234", "Number 29", "Phibsboro", "Dublin 10",  
       "11111", "uk");
       mytestdata.Rows.Add("4312", "Number 52", "Dundrum", "Dublin 18",     
       "23422", "Ireland");

       mytestdata.Rows.Add("5467", "Number 19", "Dundrum", "Dublin 19",  
      "11111", "Ireland");
       mytestdata.Rows.Add("4352", "Number 21", "Phibsboro", "Dublin 24",  
       "125632", "uk");
       mytestdata.Rows.Add("6543", "Number 15", "Dundrum", "Dublin 19",   
       "11111", "Ireland");
       mytestdata.Rows.Add("5785", "Number 24", "Phibsboro", "Dublin 12",   
       "11111", "uk");
     }

     mytestdata = (DataTable)Session["DataTable"];
     ucModalCrud._dtCRUD = mytestdata;

     ucModalCrud._pathToAddViewRecordUserControl =                             "~/PortalFramework/Shared/ModalCRUD/ForTesting/ucViewRecordDetails.ascx";
     ucModalCrud._pathToAddNewRecordUserControl = "~/PortalFramework/Shared/ModalCRUD/ForTesting/ucAddDetails.ascx";

//}

}
```

Following is the code in the usercontrol

```
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){

    DataTable mytestdata = new DataTable();
    mytestdata = (DataTable)Session["DataTable"];

    mytestdata.Rows.Add(txtID.Text, txtAddress1.Text, txtStreet.Text,    
    txtCity.Text, txtPostCode.Text, txtCountry.Text);
    Session["DataTable"] = mytestdata;

}
```

I need a way to persist the same DataTable throughout the website

Answer (score 0):

DataTables are pretty heavy objects and are not recommended to be stored in ViewState or Session for that matter. The scenario you describe is about caching data. So, you can use ASP.NET cache for storing the datatable and reusing it within the application. See an example at *[How to store datatable in cache to reuse it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6831665/how-to-store-datatable-in-cache-to-reuse-it).*

Comment: While somewhat useful, this answer would be more helpful if it included an example of how to use the ASP.NET cache directly rather than linking to another page. It also doesn't address OP's direct concern of why the DataTable doesn't persist. Is that behavior by design? Or is it due to how OP is using/calling it?