# C# Winform, Load large XML into dataset/list<Obj> once and then Access it all over the project

Tags: c#, xml, winforms

i am working on c# win form project that stores name,phone No into XML file and display all data back to data grid view. File size is increasing day by day , I need this data multiple times on different forms, and parsing XML file every time is very costly. i would like to load XML file once and then use it where ever i need in my application but i do not know how can i perform this methodology in my project. Kindly guide me about best Approach for this problem.

Comment: Global variables? Load the XML in a class and save it somewhere in the project **namespace**.

Comment: Caching the data for how much ever time you need it, would be a solution.

Comment: at the loading of the app. Load the complete xml in Object and till the program runs. manipulate the object not the file. then while unloading / exit save the XML back .

Comment: but question is about where should i load xml in a class (Program.cs ?) and how can i use this class on all over the form

Comment: Parsing the XML is Costly in what sense? time?

Comment: yes i have 200 MB file and it takes time to load into class object.

Comment: I recommend that you load it using a BackGroundWorker so the form doesn't freeze while you are parsing the xml.

Answer (score 0):

Caching the parsed XML till it is needed is a solution to this.

Caching is a concept of storing the data in a Cache of the webserver for easy access if the data is being used multiple times, since querying the database each time would be laggy.

You can use the cached data instead of Querying the database each time you need something.

if you already have the XML parsed once, you can store it as a cached variable.

Look at this Question [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6831665/how-to-store-datatable-in-cache-to-reuse-it). It explains how exactly caching texhnique is used.

Hope this helps....

Thank you!

Comment: Does it Cost effective holding data-table of 20000 rows into Caching Memory.

Comment: @MuhammadALi it depends... 

if finance is a constraint, you would probably store the data in some session variable... this is not a good idea.. it would slow down the page load time and stuff....

Comment: you could split and order the table properly in order not to load everything everytime